# Задача по RegExp

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть поле ввода, мы вводим число и оно выводит так
Ввод 1172458
Вывод (1172) (458) всмысле выводит первые четыре цифры и последные три это нужно сделать без splice или стринг метода, есть варианты?

```html
<input type = 'number'>
<button>OK </button>
<p class = "first"></p>
<p class = "second"></p>
```

Comment: Если это задача на регулярные выражения, то как ее решить без методов String? Ведь почти все методы для работы с регулярками -- это методы String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let first = document.querySelector('.first'),
    last = document.querySelector('.second');
    
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  let val = document.querySelector('input').value;
  first.innerText = val.match(/^\d{4}/);
  last.innerText = val.match(/\d{3}$/);
});

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
  evt.target.value = evt.target.value.replace(/[^\d]/, '');
});
```

```html
<input type = 'number'>
<button>OK </button>
<p class = "first"></p>
<p class = "second"></p>
```